# Convert array of unicode code points to string

Tags: arrays, swift, string, unicode

Given an array of strings that represent unicode code points:

```
let arr : [String] = ["0023", "FE0F", "20E3"]
```

How can I dynamically convert this into a swift string? Statically, I have found I can write:

```
let str = "\u{0023}\u{FE0F}\u{20E3}"
```

However, I would like to do this dynamically as each array will represent some sequence of code points. In the above example, the output would be `#️⃣`

Comment: Related: [Dynamically create NSString with unicode emoji](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38125210)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can convert each of your hexa string to `UInt32`, initialise an `Unicode.Scalar` for each element and create a `String` `UnicodeScalarView` from it:

```
let arr = ["0023", "FE0F", "20E3"]
let values = arr.compactMap{ UInt32($0, radix: 16) }
let unicodeScalars = values.compactMap(Unicode.Scalar.init)
let string = String(String.UnicodeScalarView(unicodeScalars))
```

---

Which can be also be written as a one liner:

```
let arr = ["0023", "FE0F", "20E3"]
let string = String(String.UnicodeScalarView(arr.compactMap{ UInt32($0, radix: 16) }.compactMap(Unicode.Scalar.init)))
```

edit/update:

If all your strings can be represented by UInt16 values you can also use String initializer `init(utf16CodeUnits: UnsafePointer<unichar>, count: Int)`as shown by @MartinR [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24757284/2303865):

```
let arr = ["0023", "FE0F", "20E3"]
let values = arr.compactMap { UInt16($0, radix: 16) }
let string = String(utf16CodeUnits: values, count: values.count)  // "#️⃣"
```