# Parse unicode character from server, iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, unicode, glyphicons

I use a paid set of linear icon's from [this website](https://icomoon.io/).

It's great! Especially in iOS I put the `.ttf` file in my projects bundle, load the font and use it in labels and buttons. I even wrote an [article about how I do this](https://medium.com/@joninsky/linear-icons-in-ios-you-will-be-happy-you-learned-this-6e9244215cdf).

My problem comes when I want to dynamically change a label based on some server value. My initial instinct was to save the unicode value as text up on the server. I simply save the the value such as `ed02` and when I pull it down into my App I add it to, let's say, a label like this.

```swift
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 20))
label.font = IconUltimate().icoUltimateFont(18)
let valueFromServer = "ed02"
label.text = "\u{\(valueFromServer)}"
```

The problem is that the line:

```swift
label.text = "\u{\(valueFromServer)}"
```

is invalid. What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to inject a unicode value from the server into my UI? My solution right now is to map the unicode value from the server using a switch statement like this:

```swift
    public func unicodeMapper(rawUnicode: String) -> String {
        switch rawUnicode {
        case "ecf5":
            let thumbs_up = "\u{ecf5}"
            return thumbs_up
        default:
            return ""
        }
    }
```

And call it like this:

```swift
let valueFromServer = "ed02"
label.text = unicodeMapper(rawUnicode: valueFromServer)
```

Anyone have any suggestions so I don't have to use a switch statement and I can just inject the value from the server?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/54270901/2303865

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
let code = "ecf5" // or whatever you got from the server
let codeint = UInt32(code, radix: 16)!
let c = UnicodeScalar(codeint)!
label.text = String(c)
```

Comment: Of course in real life you should not just blithely use exclamation marks like that. :)

Comment: Does that work for your purposes? I can't really test because you're mapping into an indeterminate area of the Unicode spectrum; I don't have glyphs at the point where you are.